# PHP Form not reconsigning its been posted

Tags: php, sql-server, post

I have  PHP query to a MSSQL Database. It Looks like this:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['form6'])) {
        $Title=$_POST['Title'];
        $Synopsis=$_POST['Synopsis'];
        $Article=$_POST['Article'];
        $DateUploaded= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $Deleted=$_POST['Deleted'];

        $myServer = "**********";
        $myUser = "**********";
        $myPass = "******";
        $myDB = "*********";

        $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
        mssql_select_db($myDB) or die;

        $dbTABLE = "Tablename";
        $query_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (Title, Synopsis, Article, DateUploaded, Deleted)   VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        addslashes($dbTABLE),
        addslashes($Title),
        addslashes($Synopsis),
        addslashes($Article),
        addslashes($DateUploaded),
        addslashes($Deleted));

        if ($result = mssql_query($query_sql, $dbhandle)) {
            print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
            header('Location: News.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Originally it was on a seperate .php file and got executed on the 'action' of the form. However to lessen the amount of redirects I moved it to the same page as the form and included that if statement at the top, to try and get it to execute on post of the form, which is named form6.

here is the form line.:

```
<FORM method="post" name="form6" id="form6" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

However all this seems to do is refesh the page, and no data is addded to the database and it does not hit the header to redirect to News.php.

I also tried it with no action, same result. My question is why doesn' this make it hit the php function/query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking the `<form` element which never actually has values in it in the line:

```
if (isset($_POST['form6']))
```

You need to check the actual form elements (inputs) to see if data is sent.

You should be checking the actual values in the likes of `$_POST['Title']` to see if data has been sent from the form.

If you want to include the form name, use a hidden field like this inside the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='form6' value='1'>
```

Comment: I'd suggect to include a hidden field with a name of 'form6'

Comment: @ZathrusWriter LOL, was just adding that in an edit as you wrote that :) +1 for the same train of though!

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="form6" value="6" />

Comment: @ImreL If he is just testing if it is set, then the value is totally meaningless.

Comment: This worked if one of you wants to put it into an answer so I can accept? Thanks you :)

Comment: @ObjectiveJ I did that like 8 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a submit button in the form, such as:

```
<form method="post" name="form6" id="form6" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="formsubmit"/>
</form>
```

Then in php you check for

```
 if (isset($_POST['formsubmit']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach that does not include making special hidden field:

add the "form6" to your action url:

```
<FORM method="post" name="form6" id="form6" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" 
      action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?form6'; ?>">
```

And if you check for form name use GET instead, but keep in mind that **other values are still in POST variable**

```
if (isset($_GET['form6'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you checking `<Form` `name` property in if condition as

```
if (isset($_POST['form6']))
```

Remove it and check like

```
if (isset($_POST['Title']))
```